# Copy file to a different location and changing the filename at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy, file-rename, shutil

I want to copy file to a different location and changing the filename at the same time:

```
from shutils import copyfile, copy
    path = os.path.join(dst, 'file_new_name.xls')
    copyfile(src, path) # or
    copy(src, path)
```

I get a `FileNotFoundError` with path : `dst\old_filename\newfilename`.

It happens because I try to copy as a different file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join the directory name of the old file path with the new file name instead:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(dst), 'file_new_name.xls')
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the fastest way is to use this right here:

At first you import *fs* on top of your document with this line

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

And than you can use it like this to copy the file to the new Location and also Change the Name at the same time.

```
fs.createReadStream('FirstLocationFile.txt').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('SecondLocationFile.txt'));
```

You could of course also add Folder paths into the Strings to decribe if they are or shall be inside a Folder.